# Using AppActivate when Window title to be activated starts with an asterisk *

Tags: powershell

Caveat: This question relates to a minor annoyance with a small GUI app I created for myself, so it's not in 'production' or used by others.

I have a text file called "_TEST_FILE.txt" open in my text editor of choice (Notepad2), and using the code below I can activate that Notepad2 window and select all the text in it (plus various other SendKeys abominations (I know!)).

```
[Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::AppActivate("_TEST_FILE")

if ($?){
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("^a")
}
```

This works because AppActivate matches on the Window title that "starts with..." the supplied string.

However, a feature of Notepad2 is that when the content of a currently open file is modified the title bar of the Notepad2 window prefixes the file name with an asterisk to indicate that changes have been made and the file needs to be re-saved.

Full title bar goes from this:

```
_TEST_FILE.txt - Notepad2
```

To this:

```
*_TEST_FILE.txt - Notepad2
```

I have tried as many combinations of AppActivate as I can think of to activate the `"*_TEST_FILE.txt"` window (single-quotes, double-quotes, escape characters, unicode, etc) but haven`t found the right recipe yet.

Is this even possible? I've not found anything close online, and I'm trying to avoid reams of code so if there isn`t a simple workaround I'm not going to worry.

But it would be great if there is a neat trick to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notepad2 is changing the title to `*(blank)Filename...` when the content was modified.

This works for me:
`[Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::AppActivate("* _TEST_FILE.txt")`

Keep in mind:

> At run time, the AppActivate function activates any running application with a title that matches Title or with a process ID that matches ProcessId. If there is no exact match, it **activates any application whose title string ends with Title**. If there is more than one application named Title, the AppActivate function arbitrarily chooses one to activate.
> [Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.interaction.appactivate?view=net-8.0)